# ERROR : No Module named Requests even after requests is installed

Tags: python, python-requests, importerror

I have pip installed as well as requests installed in one of udacity's workstation. When I try to run a python script which contains

```
import requests
```

It gives me an error.

[image: Error shown while running code]

I tried running running

```
pip install requests
```

But it says requirement already satisfied.

[image: requirement already satisfied]

How can i solve this issue.

Comment: make sure your pip is aligned to the correct python interpreter. i.e. the python you run the script with is the same one as the python you pip installed `requests` for

Comment: Have you tried restarting the IDE?

Comment: make sure you are using correct virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the right python version if not try using the other python versions instead. OR you could say `pip install Module==Moduleversion`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pip install chardet2 urllib3
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install requests
```

There is a problem with package dependency